# Accessing Observable object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently learning Angular through some tutorial and I came across a problem. I don't quite understand why is my console giving me error
 `ERROR in src/app/employee/employee.component.ts:17:24 - error TS2322: Type 'IEmployee' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.17     .subscribe(data => this.employees = data);`
This is my code that I followed from tutorial:

```
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public employees = [];

  constructor(private _employeeService : EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._employeeService.getEmployees()
    .subscribe(data => this.employees = data);
    console.log(this.employees);
  }

}
```

Http request should return observable with type of IEmployees interface that i made, but it doesn't work unless I do this `public employees:any = []`.This did solve my problem, but i don't understand why, since on tutorial it works without it. My second issue is when i try to Console log my employees array after i get my data with http request, to see what type of data it is, but it seems to be empty(i tried `this.employees[0].name` also). Why cannot I access that array within `ngOnInit()` but in my html file i can do it with `ngFor` and access object properties.
This is IEmployees interface

```
export interface IEmployee {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    age : number
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring your employees array,

do this

`public employees: IEmployee = [] ;`

instead of this

`public employees = []`;

This is because your service is retuning the data of type `IEmployee` while the variable you're is using is not of that type

Comment: I forgot to mention that, but i already tried that beofre, i get this ` ERROR in src/app/employee/employee.component.ts:12:10 - error TS2739: Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IEmployee': id, name, age

    12   public employees: IEmployee = [] ;
`

Comment: then check, there must be some difference in the properties of data that your service is returning and the interface that you've declared

Answer (score 0):

The `this.employees[0]` is `undefined` in `ngOnInit` because the asynchronous request finishes later, than the `ngOnInit` finishes. So the value of `this.employees` will be assigned after the `ngOnInit` is done. The `ngFor` is also able to display the values of the property after the asynchronous response arrived.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, so if i want to manipulate that data, i can do it only within subscribe method?

Comment: Yes, the content of `subscribe` is called when the response is received. You are able to manipulate the received data there.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be unsure whether you're going to receive a single Employee object or an array of Employees.

You have declared the getEmployees method in your Employee service to return an Observable<Employee>.

If your API returns an array of Employees, change the getEmployees method such that it returns an Observable<Employee[]>.

If your API returns a single Employee object, change the arrow function to the following:
data => this.employees = [data].

To additionally log the output to the console, change the arrow function to:
data => { console.log(data); // set this.employees;}